# Meaning of this code "suspend fun get(url: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){/*...*/}"

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to android development.When I was reading medium post https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-i-getting-the-background-3e0e54d20bb I came across this code:

```
suspend fun get(url: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){/*...*/}
```

which I could not understand. I have tried Search but I could not find  code with similar syntax.Can somebody please explain it?

Comment: That article tries to explain that particular block of code. It may help to quote any article text that you don't comprehend and if you have experience with threads in any computer language.

Answer (score 1):

It's releated to `asynchronous` or `non-blocking` programming using [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html). It's a suspending function which can suspend the execution of a coroutine.

The `withContext` lets your function return a value ( you can also use `launch` which will return a job ).

From docs:

`Calls the specified suspending block with a given coroutine context, suspends until it completes, and returns the result.` [Read more here.](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html)

The `Dispatchers.IO` is the default instance of coroutine dispatcher for background coroutine. [Read more here.](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/index.html)